# OpenLayers 3 dragBox on mobile

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I'm currently implementing a dragBox to select multiple vectors at once.
Since the dragBox object requires a "condition:" and in the official example it is a keyPress, "shift" I think, I have set up a singleton boolean variable in Angular that will set the condition to "ol.events.condition.always" or "ol.events.condition.never"  which the object accepts and works fine on a computer...however does not work on mobile, I thought this might work on mobile something like drawing a circle but does not.

Is there a way to make this work on mobile?

Here's my code.

```
 mapFeature.addDragBox = function () {

            webMapValues.dragBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
                /* dragbox interaction is active only if "multi select" 
check box is checked is pressed */
                condition: ((webMapValues.multiSelect == true) ? 
ol.events.condition.always : ol.events.condition.never),
                /* style the box */
                style: new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: [0, 0, 255, 1]
                    })
                })
            });
            /* add the DragBox interaction to the map */
            webMapValues.mapObj.addInteraction(webMapValues.dragBox);

            if (webMapValues.multiSelect == true) {
                webMapValues.vectorMultiSelect = new 
ol.interaction.Select();

webMapValues.mapObj.addInteraction(webMapValues.vectorMultiSelect);

                webMapValues.multiSelectFeatures = 
webMapValues.vectorMultiSelect.getFeatures();
                webMapValues.dragBox.on('boxend', function () {
                    // features that intersect the box are added to the 
collection of
                    // selected features
                    webMapValues.clickedCoordinates = 
webMapValues.dragBox.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                    var extent = 
webMapValues.dragBox.getGeometry().getExtent();
                    var layer = rcisMapService.getLayer("vector");
                    angular.forEach(layer, function (Layer, key) {
                        var source = Layer.getSource();
                        source.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(extent, 
function (feature) {

webMapValues.multiSelectedFeatures.push(vector);
                        });
                    });
                    mapFeature.Highlight();

                });

                webMapValues.dragBox.on('boxstart', function () {
                    webMapValues.popup.setPosition(undefined);
                    webMapValues.multiSelectedFeatures = [];
                });
            }

        };
```

Comment: The API doc says "This interaction is only supported for mouse devices.", so no, it is not possible. I guess the problem is that there are not enough gestures to distinguish between map-move, zoom and draw at the same time. (see http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.DragBox.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to "Drag" on a mobile device doesn't exist in OpenLayers 3...the closest thing to it using the "Draw" feature to draw a square and then get everything that intersects with that square.

```
 if (selectionToolsSelection == "Box") {
                var geometryFunction = ol.interaction.Draw.createBox();
                drawObj = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                    features: features,
                    type: "Circle",
                    geometryFunction: geometryFunction
                });
                mapObj.addInteraction(drawObj);

            }
```

Then you can catch the "drawend" event and do what you need to ...

```
  drawObj.on('drawend', function (e) {Do magic stuff here});
```

Answer (score 0):

Touch devices are supported for dragboxes by setting the condition option to `mouseActionButton` (see: [Pull Request: Support touch events for `DragBox` interaction](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/10321))

```js
import {mouseActionButton} from 'ol/events/condition';

const dragBox = new DragBox({
  condition: mouseActionButton,
});
```